# Stop Php Execute in page

Tags: php

I have added This Code in My Domain2 where i want this code to be executed Running If it From domain 1

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['id2'])) { $id2=$_GET['id2']; echo "www.xxxxxxxxxx"" ></iframe>";}
                                                    else
{
echo "Not Found";

}
```

I try this code but not working
If anyone direct accesses this https://Domain2.com/xxxxxxxx/?id=xxxx  Hidden part of is showing
How to make hidden if it not Redirected By https://Domain1.com/away.php

Comment: You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's not guaranteed to be set or accurate and then `exit`.

Comment: You want to check if it was redirected from domain1 by using `id` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to make sure that the refering page (previous page) was the one that you expect:

```
<?php 
// if the request comes from a file that contains the string "conforming.php" then render the page
    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "conforming.php")) {
         //serve page if came from conforming.php
     }
// if the referring page is not conforming.php, then redirect the user to the conforming version
    else  {
        header("Location: conforming.php");
    }
?>
```

additional information: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SVR3.html

*****EDIT*******
I customized the code below according to your additional requirements:

```
<?php 

if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "https://Domain1.com/away.php"))
{
    if (isset($_GET['id2']))
    {
        $id2 = $_GET['id2'];
        echo "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"560\" height=\"320\" src=\"https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/files.php?v=$id2\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\" ></iframe>";
    } else{
        echo "id is empty";
    }
    
}
else
{
    //invalid referer! go back to domain1 to make it valid!
    header("Location: https://Domain2.com/xxxxxxxx/");
}

?>
```

Comment: I try this Direct url executed <?php if(isset($_GET['id2'])) { $id2=$_GET['id2']; echo "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"560\" height=\"320\" src=\"https://www.xxxxxx.com/files.php?v=$id2\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\" ></iframe>";}
                                                    else
{
echo "Stop";

}

    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/away.php")) {
         //serve page if came from conforming.php
     }

    else  {
        header("Location: xxxxxxxxx");
    }
?>

Comment: You can check first $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] before processing the iframes.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I edit the question can you please check and fix my code

Comment: good to hear that!

Comment: Just beware that it's easy to spoof a referer value, so it only provides very minimal security

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is exit;

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{ 
  $id1=$_GET['id']; echo "xxxxxxxxxx=$id1";}
else {
  echo "stop";
  exit;
}

?>
```

Exit will terminate the execution of the current script. This will then continue with the execution processes, which will call your next function.

More reading here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: if the id= nothing in URL it shows word stop

Comment: Yup thats perfect. its doing what you wrote now. Its echo'd stop and then exited out of the script. your code is working perfect. id is not set to anything in your 'else' and its only getting in there if id  is not set.